# Schluter profile wall tile layout strategy

Tags: walls, tile

Long time lurker, first time poster.

I would like to install a ~4-foot tile half-wall in my bathroom, using 3x8 tiles. I will be using Schluter Quadec edge profiles on the tops and sides instead of bullnose. I usually tile from bottom to top, cutting in a perfectly level first row, where small goofs can be covered with caulk. My question is: would it be easier in this case to set the Quadec at the height of 48 inches (16 tiles + 17 1/16" grout lines with 15/16" nominally cut off the bottom to hide levelness irregularities), then work top to bottom from the profile to the floor?

Edit for those who might stumble across this:
I did exactly this. I mixed a pot of good modified thinset (Schluter all-set) on the stiffer side. Then, using a laser level, I made the quadec perfectly level and worked my way left-to-right, high-to-low. I had minor sagging issues in the first 30 minutes or so, when the thinset was fresher, but I was able to correct those as I went.

Comment: not many know more than you

Comment: I would start at the bottom. Tiles have a tendency to slide down. I would put a ledger board and lay my first row on top of that. Once they're set remove the board and fill in the bottom row. Leaving it as a comment because there's others on here that do this for a living and can give a better answer.

Comment: "Would it be easier..." gets a knee-jerk "Opinion based" vote to close because we don't know your skills. "Would there be drawbacks to..." is more objective and answerable. You may want to make a quick [edit] to your question, take the [tour] and browse through the "How to Ask" section of the [help].